# popToRootViewController not removing prompt

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have an app that prompts the user for various information before doing a task. Once all the information is put in by the user, I do a `UIApplication.shared.openUrl(url: url)` and then `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`. The app pops back to the root view controller; however, the navigation item prompt from the last view controller is now included in the navigation item of the root view controller.

Anyone understand why this is happening and a good way to fix it? I could just set the prompt to `""` when the root view controller reappears, but I would like to solve the problem, not alleviate the symptom.

**Update**

Per @Shad 's answer, I've updated my view controller with the code below and everything is working as expected.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)    
    self.navigationItem.prompt = nil
}
```

Comment: What navigation item prompt? Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I have no code for setting the navigation item prompt. The navigation item prompts are all static in the storyboard files.

Comment: I tried to re-produce what you got, but I don't have any issue.

Comment: in the view Will disappear of the viewcontroller remove the prompt. That should fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your **prompts** is added to window and is visible even the parent View-Controller, on which the **prompts** was added, is not currently visible. We can go on details if you share some code.

However there is a way to dismiss the prompts before going back to RootViewController.
You can use the `-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` to dismiss the **prompts**. Just remove the **prompts** view from the parent View-Controller by calling `removeFromSuperview()` on the `-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`. Assuming your **prompts** is a UIView.

Comment: this solved my problem. however, I don't think it would work in the case of another view controller coming onto the stack (such as a modal). that would cause the prompt to be empty upon returning to the last view controller. i'm still curious as to why this is happening...

Comment: I have no code setting the prompt other than what you suggested in viewWillDisappear. The prompt messages are all set in storyboard files.